# String command as superuser

Tags: linux, string, terminal, command, superuser

I found out that if you want to execute a command as superuser you need to add the following: 
`echo <password> | sudo -s <command>` .

First I wanted to suspend the Linux server with 
`echo <password> | sudo -s pm-suspend`, and it worked fine.
Now I want to execute the command `echo -e "\xff\x01\x00" > /dev/ttyUSB0`

`echo <password> | sudo -s echo -e "\xff\x01\x00" > /dev/ttyUSB0` does not work, I guess because of the ">" in it. What changes are needed to get the command working?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, never use `echo password | ...`. on the command line. This is insecure as the password would remain in the history file, plus other users can see the password using the `ps` command. If you want to execute a `sudo` command without entering a password you can use the `NOPASSWD` option in `/etc/sudoers`. Check this: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/18830/how-to-run-a-specific-program-as-root-without-a-password-prompt

---

About the permission problem. You are right, the problem is the output redirection `>`. You need to know that the shell will open the output file, *not* the command running with `sudo`.

In this example:

```
sudo command > output.file
```

the shell tries to open `output.file`, then starts `sudo command` and set  it's standard output to the open file. However, the shell does not have root permissions.

A workaround could be to use the `tee` command, like this:

```
command | sudo tee output.file
```

however, I would simply grant proper permissions to edit that file. On example way could be to create a group, change the group ownership of that file and you into that group. For example:

```
# Add group
sudo groupadd developers

# Change group ownership of the file
sudo chown root:developers output.file

# make the file writable by the group
sudo chmod g+w output.file

# Finally put you into that group
sudo usermod -a -G developers YOU
```

But if you are an admistrative user, meaning you can execute every command with `sudo`, the `tee` solution above is good enough.

Comment: How to grant those proper permissions?

Comment: You are welcome! Keep in mind that you should never pass a password via the command line.